# Profile:edit / Safecracker current password not recognized

Tags: safecracker, profile-edit

I am working on a member profile edit using Profile:edit and a safecracker form. There is just one small problem.

When I try to make changes to the profile (not as a super admin) it requires the current password. The documentation provides the following code, which I have tried, but I still get an error.

The code:

```
{exp:profile:edit return="/member-area/company-preview" form_class="profile"}

{if logged_in_group_id != 1}
  <p>(You must submit the current password to update this page)</p>
  <label><span>Your Current Password:</span>
   <input type="password" name="current_password" value="" />
  </label>
{/if}
<fieldset>
<label><span>Username:</span>
    <input type="text" name="username" value="{username}" />
        </label>

        <label><span>Screen Name:</span>
            <input type="text" name="screen_name" value="{screen_name}" />
        </label>

        <label><span>Email:</span>
            <input type="text" name="email" value="{email}" />
        </label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <p>Change password? Leave blank if you do not wish to change it.</p>
        <label><span>New Password</span>
            <input type="password" name="password" value="" />
        </label>

        <label><span>Confirm New Password</span>
            <input type="password" name="password_confirm" value="" />
        </label>

            {!-- superadmins don't have to submit existing password --}
            {if logged_in_group_id != 1}
                <p>(You must submit the current password to update this page)</p>
                <label><span>Your Current Password:</span>
                    <input type="password" name="current_password" value="" />
                </label>
            {/if}
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <label><span>*First Name:</span>
        {field:member_first_name}
    </label>

    <label><span>*Last Name:</span>
        {field:member_last_name}
    </label>

    <label><span>*Full Name:</span>
        {field:full_name}
    </label>

    <label><span>Address:</span>
        {field:member_address}
    </label>

    <label><span>Address:</span>
        {field:member_address2}
    </label>

    <label><span>City:</span>
        {field:member_city}
    </label>

    <label><span>State:</span>
        {field:member_state}
    </label>

    <label><span>Zip:</span>
        {field:member_zip}
    </label>

    <label><span>Main Phone:</span>
        {field:member_phone}
    </label>


    <fieldset>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </fieldset>
{/exp:profile:edit}
```

The error message:

> In order to make changes you must submit the current password

I would appreciate any assistance resolving this.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the complete code for the form you are using so we can see the outer tags as well.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem. I updated the module from 1.0.7 to 1.0.9 and the problem went away.